# Why the complex logarithm function$\ln(z)$ is not meromorphic on the whole complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

About meromorphic function, [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) says:

> In the mathematical field of complex analysis, a meromorphic function
>   on an open subset D of the complex plane is a function that is
>   holomorphic on all D except a set of isolated points (the poles of the
>   function), at each of which the function must have a Laurent series.

, and as an example, it says

> The complex logarithm function  $f(z) = \ln(z)$  is not meromorphic on
>   the whole complex plane, as it cannot be defined on the whole complex
>   plane while only excluding an isolated set of points.

I don't understand the idea here, why $\ln(z)$ is not meromorphic.

Is this because  the complex exponential function is not injective, hence $\ln(z)$ has many many branches? If so, if we limit to the principal value $\text{Log } z$ where the logarithm imaginary part lies in the interval $(−\pi, \pi]$, would that $\text{Log } z$ be meromorphic?

Comment: Meromorphic functions can only have isolated pole singularities. A branch cut is a line, not an isolated singularity. Ergo, $\ln(z)$ cannot be a meromorphic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $z=re^{i\theta}$. If we want a $\log$ function with the expected properties,
$$\log z=\log r+i\theta=|z|+i\arg z.$$
But isn't possible define an $\arg$ function without a jump (why?).

Comment: is it because there's a jump at right side of the x axis?

Comment: Even more: with *any* possible definition of $\arg$. Do full turn around the origin.

Comment: "Do full turn around the origin" -- i don't get it...

Comment: Typo correction: "Do *a* full turn". Like the point $(\cos t,\sin t)$ when $t$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$.